# VBA code to automatically import "NEWEST" csv file into specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to write a VBA code to import the newest .csv file from a certain directory into a specific excel sheet. I am currently using a code that works, BUT it opens up in a new workbook and I cannot figure out how to append it to a certain sheet instead. If that makes sense? Also, is there a way to also delete all duplicates within that specific sheet after imported?

The code I am currently using through VBA is below....

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewestFile()

    Dim MyPath As String

    Dim MyFile As String

    Dim LatestFile As String

    Dim LatestDate As Date

    Dim LMD As Date

    MyPath = "C:\Users\Documents\"

    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then

        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation

        Exit Sub

    End If

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

        If LMD > LatestDate Then

            LatestFile = MyFile

            LatestDate = LMD

        End If

        MyFile = Dir

    Loop

    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

End Sub
```

The issue is that this code opens up in a new workbook instead of importing into a specific sheet.

Comment: Where is this code located (workbook?)? Where is the 'appending' worksheet located (workbook?)? What exactly needs to be appended? what exactly makes a record (row) a duplicate (one or more columns?)? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72311586/edit) at any time.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sorry about that!! The code is located within a Budgeting excel workbook that I am using for personal finance, and then using the VBA developer tools to write the code for excel to achieve this. It can be a duplicate if the banking transactions imported from the CSV file, are the same. So I am importing this CSV file that contains transactions, into a sheet on my work book labeled "Transactions".

Comment: Of course it does. What do you think `Workbooks.Open` means other than "open a workbook"?

Comment: Well I'm definitely new to coding, and just trying to figure out is all.... Is there an alternative to use instead of Workbooks.Open? What would I need to use to append that to a certain sheet? Thanks

Comment: Some options: 1. Copy data from your new workbook to your existing worksheet; 2. `Worksheet.QueryTables.Add`; 3. `Workbook.Queries.Add`; 4. Use `Power Query` instead of `VBA`.

Comment: So should I use the "Worksheet.QueryTables.Add" code, does that import into a specific worksheet? I am sorry I am new to VBA. So your saying the following code should append to a certain sheet within that workbook?Option Explicit

Sub NewestFile()
    End If

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

        If LMD > LatestDate Then

            LatestFile = MyFile

            LatestDate = LMD

        End If

        MyFile = Dir

    Loop

    Workbook.Queries.Add MyPath & LatestFile

End Sub